# How to get "opam init --comp=..." to install at the latest OCaml version?

Tags: ocaml, opam

If there is no version of OCaml already installed on the computer, running `opam init` will ask you to specify a version of OCaml to install by default. That's great.

Is there a way to ask it to install the latest released version? It would make scripting the installation easier than having to look up what is the latest version each time.

Answer (score 3):

Well I got no answers so I came up with the following:

```
latest=$(
    curl -s "https://opam.ocaml.org/urls.txt"                            | \
        sed -n -e '/^compilers/ s/^compilers\/\([0-9.]*\)\/\1\/.*$/\1/p' | \
        sort -rn | head -n1)

opam init --comp="${latest}"
```

Seems to work.

Comment: @Str. Sorry for solving my own problem and posting the answer in case others are interested.